# mediaelement 'playing' event tracking

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mediaelement.js

I have the following simple code that initiates the `mediaelement` audio plugin:

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: 300,
    audioHeight: 30
});
```

I need to track the `playing` event; I've tried the following code without any luck:

```
var player = document.getElementsById('player2');
player.playing = function(e) {
   alert('OMG! You played a song!');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so I've figured it out...

```
$('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
    audioWidth: 300,
    audioHeight: 30,

    success: function(mediaElement, domObject) {
        mediaElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
            console.log('addEventListener - loadeddata')            
        }, false);
    },
    error: function() {
        //alert('Error setting media!');
    }

});
```

Comment: Works with jQuery as well: `$(mediaElement).on('loadeddata', function() { ... });`

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
# using jquery (on, bind, etc)...
$('#player1').bind('playing', function(e) { 
   console.log('bind - playing') 
});

# addEventListener 
var player = document.getElementById('player1'); 
player.addEventListener('playing', function(e) {
   console.log('addEventListener - playing') ;
});
```

Comment: Are you using a library? ie: http://mediaelementjs.com/? This is what i assumed you were using. Also, be sure to replace '#player1' with the id of your player element.

Comment: Yes I am using mediaelemtjs.com. I've changed the id's to the appropiate names too

Comment: Hmm... strange. If you visit mediaelementjs.com -> open developer's console and pase any of the provided logic, it works. Are you able to console log your player to ensure you're getting a correct reference to it?

Comment: Should be the same deal. $('audio').bind('playing', function(e) { console.log('audio'); }) works on their page for the audio element. Maybe if you provide more sample code, it can be sorted out.

Comment: Looks like your player is not downloading the file base on what I am seeing. I would verify the file is able to load up in the player. hitting play does nothing, which is likely why you're not getting an event.

Comment: Hmm are you sure? I've tried in both FF and Chrome and its working fine for me.

Comment: I use a mac. It worked in Safari just now but wasn't working initially.

Comment: Hmm strange, are you able to log anything then or still nothing? Considering using soundmanager2 instead.

Comment: No errors. It's working, but still not able to get the events.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

A little late but had to solve this one myself. I noted that the MediaElement docs say that the success function first argument is a mediaElement object. It just so happens that the player html is wrapped inside a  element, no matter what type of video it is. You can't access it directly as a jQuery object but a simple tweak fixes it all.

The following is used to fetch the closest player no matter which element you pass in

```
function getVideo(el) {
    var $el = $(el);

    if ($el.find('mediaelementwrapper').length) {
        return $el.find('mediaelementwrapper')[0];
    } else if ($el.parents('mediaelementwrapper').length) {
        return $el.parents('mediaelementwrapper')[0];
    }

    return $el.is('mediaelementwrapper') ? $el : false;
}
```

Notice we have to access it via [0] returning the document node rather than jQuery object.

But from there we can use it like this.

```
$video = getVideo('#playerID');

$video.addEventListener('playing', function () {
    debugger;
}, false);
```

Or do it without the helper

```
$video = jQuery('#playerID mediaelementwrapper')[0];
```